# npm: Add dependecy from existing dependency tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a Vue app that uses `vuetable-2` and `vue-axios`, with the following imports in `app.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMaterial from 'vue-material'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
```

Without having `axios` directly in `package.json`'s dependencies section, eslint will complain

```
[eslint] 'axios' should be listed in the project's dependencies.
```

I already have `axios` in `./node_modules` as part of the `vue-axios` dependencies.

```
└─┬ vuetable-2@1.6.6
  └── axios@0.15.3
```

Running `npm install --save axios` will fetch the latest version of `axios` and add it to `package.json`, but now I have 2 versions of axios in my dependencies

```
├── axios@0.17.0 
└─┬ vuetable-2@1.6.6
  └── axios@0.15.3
```

How can I re-use `axios@0.15.3` that is part of the `vuetable-2` dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget about exact version

write in package.json without ^
or type `npm i axios@0.15.3 -S -E`

> -E, --save-exact: Saved dependencies will be configured with an exact version rather than using npm's default semver range operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add it to the dependencies in `package.json` yourself:

```
"axios": "^0.15.3"
```

So for example your `package.json` might look like:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "vuetable-2": "^1.6.6",
        "axios": "^0.15.3"
    }
}
```

Although obviously you would have more dependencies etc.

Once that is done, just run

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just install the same `axios` version which used in the `vuetable-2`, just run following code:

`npm i axios@0.15.3 -S`